# Task.Run a method who raise events

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, task

In a Windows Store application, written in WPF and C#, I need to launch an async method who gather informations from files.  But I want it to run in background while to UI is responsive to user interactions.  So, I did this :

```
Task x = Task.Run(async () => await Method());
```

The problem is, "Method" must raise change notifications to the UI.  As you can expect, it crashed because the method who raise the event is not in the UI thread.

So, I did this :

```
TaskScheduler t = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronisationContext();
Task x = Task.Run(() => {}).ContinueWith(async _ => await Method(), t);
```

My question is, as I must specify a synchronization context, and as there is no way to specify it in the Run method, is there a way to do something like this :

```
TaskScheduler t = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronisationContext();
Task x = Task.ContinueWith(async _ => await Method(), t);
```

Or, if you have another suggestion to make it work, it is welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to run a method in *Task* which can send UI notifications. What is wrong with a simple `Method();`

Comment: @L.B Because the OP says the UI must be responsive. If `Method()` does CPU-Bound operations the UI can become unresponsive.

Comment: @AsadAli If a method can send events to UI thread, then it means it already does some things asynchronously. Otherwise it would be meaningless. clear?

Comment: @L.B Not really. Why is that?

Comment: The OP says nothing about CPU bound work. I still see no reason for a new thread?

Comment: @L.B Method() do the dababase initialisation and file synchronisation operations.  The code above is in the OnLaunched method of App.Xaml.cs.  If I don't do that, the splash screen is displayed until the awaited method finish. I suppose the call into the main page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to spin up a new `Task` at all. You can simply `await Method()` without needing to use `ContinueWith` on `Task` which consumes a ThreadPool thrrad.. When you `await` on an async method, it will run synchronously until hitting the first `await` and return back to the calling method, which will keep your UI responsive

You can simply

```
await Method();
```

Comment: You are wright.  To be honest, I don't grasp the entire async notion yet.  The example code was in the OnLaunched method of the App.xaml.cs file.  I moved it in the main page and is executed in the loaded event.  I only call Method() with an await and it seems ok.  I suppose the long execution Method() do will not stop if I change the current page as it is in another thread, am I wright?

Comment: I am not sure of something though.  I will make some more tests before telling this solved my problem.

Comment: @sbeaudoin What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Yes, it works.  I had a usercontrol in the page who did not show, so I thought my long process was blocking it, but no, it was a code error.  Sorry though, I can't give you +1 as I don't have 15 reputation.  I marked this as a solution.